# Debug OpenCL kernel

Tags: debugging, kernel, opencl

I am working with OpenCL and I have many problems with the pointers(segmentation violation). How I can debug the kernel code for GPU to see the memory where I am putting my atributes and see my mistakes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were/are some GPU debugging tools, but another method is to use the Intel CPU driver and debug using a CPU debugger. Here's an article from Intel on how to do it:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/539339

Alternatively, since it's C99, you can just move the kernel code into a regular C/C++ program and get the logic working there first, and then move it to a kernel.